# Transform a Python script into a .NET 6 API for generating summaries

Tags: python, c#, .net-6.0

I have a straightforward .NET 6 API that invokes a Python script to produce text summaries.
The issue arises when I make a second call to the controller, and the API becomes unresponsive at this point at the line

```
using (Py.GIL())
```

It appears that a deadlock is hindering the lock's execution.
Interestingly, when I execute the code in a Windows or console application and repeatedly make the same call, it functions as expected without deadlocks.

Here's the code,

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using TextSummaries;

namespace CreateSummaries.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class CreateNltkSummariesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Summaries createSummaries;

        public CreateNltkSummariesController()
        {
            createSummaries = new Summaries();
        }

        [HttpPost(Name = "NltkSummarise")]
        public IActionResult NltkSummarise([FromBody] string input)
        {
            var output = createSummaries.NltkSummarise(input);

            return Ok(output);
        }
    }
}

using Python.Runtime;

namespace TextSummaries
{
    public class Summaries
    {
        private readonly string pythonPath = @"C:\Python\Python311\python311.dll";

        public string NltkSummarise(string inputText)
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONNET_PYDLL", pythonPath);
            PythonEngine.Initialize();

            using (Py.GIL())
            {
                dynamic py = Py.Import("nltksummarise");
                dynamic summary = py.summarize_text(inputText);
                return summary;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

the program.cs file

```
using System.Net;
using System.Reflection.PortableExecutable;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();
app.UseHsts();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

the python file nltksummarise.py

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
from nltk import PorterStemmer
from heapq import nlargest  # Import nlargest from heapq

def summarize_text(text, num_sentences=20):

    # Tokenize the text into sentences
    sentences = sent_tokenize(text)

    # Tokenize the text into words
    words = word_tokenize(text)

    # Remove stopwords
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    filtered_words = [word for word in words if word.lower() not in stop_words]

    # Calculate word frequencies
    word_freq = FreqDist(filtered_words)

    # Calculate sentence scores based on word frequencies
    sentence_scores = {}
    for sentence in sentences:
        for word in word_tokenize(sentence):
            if word.lower() in word_freq:
                if sentence not in sentence_scores:
                    sentence_scores[sentence] = word_freq[word.lower()]
                else:
                    sentence_scores[sentence] += word_freq[word.lower()]

    summary_sentences = nlargest(num_sentences, sentence_scores, key=sentence_scores.get)

    # Combine the summary sentences into a single string
    summary = TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize(summary_sentences)

    return summary
```